# Best practices/popular methods for distributing a program with a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, third-party-applications

Are there any best practice guidelines regarding how a plugin should distribute a third-party program with it's own installation?  If there are no guidelines, then what are the most popular methods?

For example, our plugin requires the installation of a third-party (GPL compatible) program.  To ease installation, the third-party program would be included with our plugin and it will offer to run a version of the program that is compatible with their hosting environment that is included in our plugins assets directory (or other directory?).  Updates to the third-party program would be handled by updating it along with our own plugins updates ([our version].[third-party-version]).

Comment: You mean a third party library?

Comment: What type of program? Where's it supposed to run?

Comment: @leymannx not a library, a program written in C++

Comment: @JacobPeattie a program that makes RPC calls available, so I'm doing service calls, but locally to the local server.

Comment: Unless this is a PHP library that can be bundled with the plugin, it has no place inside a plugin, and should be distributed separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

their [rules](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/#8-plugins-may-not-send-executable-code-via-third-party-systems) specifically say

> Externally loading code from documented services is permitted.

however all the related examples are about javascript or wordpress plugins.

> Management services that interact with and push software down to a site are permitted, provided the service handles the interaction on it’s own domain and not within the WordPress dashboard.

which doesn't apply since I'm not providing a remote service but a local service. (unless an http download counts as a "management service")

I emailed `plugins@wordpress.org` and got an official response.

> You cannot include the binary, nor can you one-click to install.

Answer (score -1):

One of the most common methods used for this is the TGMPA plugin:
http://tgmpluginactivation.com/

Which supports customizing the `source` for the plugin, if it's not a standard WordPress repository plugin:
http://tgmpluginactivation.com/configuration/